Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static contex error using Comparator
Even after reading documentations and multiple posts about this error I still don't understand the following case:
This line will generate the error Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static contex error
on Comparator.comparingInt(Pair::getLeft)
Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>> compareByName  = Comparator.comparingInt(Pair::getLeft)
                                                              .thenComparing(Pair::getRight);

This line will be ok:
Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>> compareByCount  = Comparator.comparingInt(Pair::getLeft);
compareByCount = compareByCount.thenComparing(Pair::getRight);

Thank you in advance for any clarification on that subject!
I am trying to use this comparator as an argument to a PriorityQueue's constructor.

See the duplicate target. The error message is a bit confusing but the root cause is the same - type inference fails and Java doesn't know the type of method that comparing should be accepting.

Hello Linda, welcome, Assuming that the title reflects the error message that your program gives you, surely you are running the call to Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>> compareByName = Comparator.comparingInt(Pair::getLeft)                                                 .thenComparing(Pair::getRight); inside the main method, which is static, that's why the message, what you must do, is to create a method in the class with your code, in the main you create an object of the class and with it, you call the created method. (NameClass cl = new NameClass();, cl.runMethod();).

Try Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>> compareByName  = Comparator.comparingInt(Pair<Integer, Integer>::getLeft) .thenComparing(Pair::getRight);

Hi, thank you all for your answers. I understand better now. To clarify, this statement is made in a public non-static method of a class; not in the Main method. @Sweeper and @Holger thank you that fixed the issue. I understand it's a type inference issue and the compiler's message is not so clear about it, which is confusing because method Comparator.comparingInt is indeed static and method Pair::getLeft is indeed non-static. Conclusion @Harel code snippet solves the issue. Thank you.
